# CodeIgniter Mod_Rewrite Issue - URL's only showing index

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have a CI app that after switching servers, doesn't seem to route properly.

In my config I have

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

This should allow both query string parameters and url segments.

So this, should in theory work (as it is on the old server):

http://www.domain.com/register?param=something

However, no matter what URL I go to it only shows the index.

So if I go to http://www.domain.com/register

It shows this in the address bar, however it doesn't get the register controller, it's showing the index.

If I change the 'uri_protocol' to REQUEST_URI, it works.  But then query string parameters won't.

My .htaccess is

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|license.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^$ /? [L]
```

Any ideas what the issue could be? Like I say, it's working on a different server.  So, I'm thinking something to do with apache perhaps?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess, `RewriteCond $1` never evaluates to true and no redirect happens.

You can, actually, reduce these two lines to one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

It's sufficient to write

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Since the `-f` test checks files *and* directories. If this still fails to produce your expected results, inspect `PATH_INFO` and `ORIG_PATH_INFO` in `$_SERVER` if they're actually present.

Comment: Thank you, still does not work however.  There's no PATH_INFO in $_SERVER, but there is ORIG_PATH_INFO which is /register

Comment: I've updated my $config['uri_protocol'] to use 'ORIG_PATH_INFO' - this works! Is this the best solution?

Comment: @dave Yes. Depending on the environment PHP runs (module, CGI, FastCGI), the actual `PATH_INFO` can be found in many an odd "alias" in `$_SERVER`.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the ./ before the index.php

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

You should actually be able to get by with just these lines

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

If you have the codeigniter in a directory, you may need to add the rewrite base directive depending on your server setup.

```
RewriteBase /directory/
```